# How to Pixelate selected area on Canvas/ImageView Android?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, canvas, paint

here is sample java code which pixelates selected area on image.

[pixelate sample in java](http://www.savthecoder.com/blog/pixelate-programmatically)

i want to achieve similar functionality in android.
searched a lot but dint find any example.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I recently put a library on Github that is able to pixelate an entire image or just a small part of that image for a specified area. https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Pixelate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.try to search for resize/re-sampling algorithms

- like bilinear filtering ...

2.average color will do it too

- make nested for loops x0,y0 through pixelated image (small resolution)
- compute average color of the pixel area in source image (big resolution)

  - this is also done by 2 nested for loops x1,y1 through pixel area
  - just sum all R,G,B values separately
  - then divide them by number of pixels
- store resulting color to pixelated image pixel(x0,y0)

[Notes]

if your pixelated image is the same resolution (or pixels' are area of pixels)

- then instead of pixelated pixel fill entire pixel area by average color

Comment: can you please share any example?

Comment: which one you need ? new image has the same resolution or the squares are individual pixels ? I do not code on your platform but I can provide code for PC ... you just will need to change the bitmap access to your platform